# Python -- how to read and change specific fields from file? (specifically, numbers)

Tags: python, scripting

I just started learning python scripting yesterday and I've already gotten stuck. :(

So I have a data file with a lot of different information in various fields.

Formatted basically like...

Name (tab) **Start#**  (tab)  **End#**  (tab) A bunch of fields I need but do not do anything with
Repeat

I need to write a script that takes the start and end numbers, and add/subtract a number accordingly depending on whether another field says + or -.

I know that I can replace words with something like this:

```
x = open("infile")
y = open("outfile","a")
while 1:
  line = f.readline()
  if not line: break
  line = line.replace("blah","blahblahblah")
  y.write(line + "\n")
y.close()
```

But I've looked at all sorts of different places and I can't figure out how to extract specific fields from each line, read one field, and change other fields. I read that you can read the lines into arrays, but can't seem to find out how to do it.

Any help would be great!

**EDIT:**

Example of a line from the data here: (Each `|` represents a tab character)

```
            |          |
            V          V
chr21 | 33025905 | 33031813 | ENST00000449339.1 | 0 | **-** | 33031813 | 33031813 | 0 | 3 | 1835,294,104, | 0,4341,5804,
chr21 | 33036618 | 33036795 | ENST00000458922.1 | 0 | **+** | 33036795 | 33036795 | 0 | 1 | 177,          | 0,
```

The second and third columns (indicated by arrows) would be the ones that I'd need to read/change.

Comment: Could you add an example of the data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `csv` to do the splitting, although for these sorts of problems, I usually just use `str.split`:

```
with open(infile) as fin,open('outfile','w') as fout:
   for line in fin:
       #use line.split('\t'3) if the name of the field can contain spaces
       name,start,end,rest = line.split(None,3)  
       #do something to change start and end here.
       #Note that `start` and `end` are strings, but they can easily be changed
       #using `int` or `float` builtins.
       fout.write('\t'.join((name,start,end,rest)))
```

---

`csv` is nice if you want to split lines like this:

```
this is a "single argument"
```

into:

```
['this','is','a','single argument']
```

but it doesn't seem like you need that here.

Comment: It would probably be best to make the split specifically on `'\t'` in case the name field contains spaces.

Comment: Actually I think csv might be more appropriate...? I edited the original question with two lines of example data, and from reading the split I can't think of a way on how I could jam all that in. Thanks for the help I'll look into csv. Are there any other ways you could think of though?

Comment: @Joe -- I think that what I posted should work on the input you showed.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski -- Added a comment in the code to address the fieldname with spaces concern.  Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Mk. Thanks for the reply. I am writing a test script right now trying the split out, but I have a question --  looking at the line.split('\t',3), I'm having trouble understanding why you put 3 there. I'm looking at the documentation and it says that number is for maximum splits, so shouldn't that be four in your example? (in my case I'd need to do something like (name, start, end, anothername, anothernumber, addorsub, rest) so I guess I'd need it to be 7)

Comment: @Joe, No, although this is a common misunderstanding.  If you have a cake, and you split that cake once, you end up with 2 pieces (One for me and one for you:).  `str.split` works the same way.  If you have 1 string and you split it once, you end up with 2 pieces.  If you split it twice, you end up with 3 pieces, ...

Comment: @Joe -- The reason I split it 3 times is because you said you didn't want to touch the rest of the fields.  You could also do `lst = line.split('\t')` and then work directly with `lst[1]` and `lst[2]` if that is more intuitive for you.

Comment: @mgilson Oh, another quick question. Is there a simple one line command here you can think of that I could add onto to your example that would make it delete the current line it's on? I just realized -- if subtracting a certain amount to start and end results in one or the other becoming a negative number, that line is useless to me. And everything I've found that deletes lines are all very complicated.

Comment: before `fout.write`:  `if condition: continue` -- where `condition` is `True-like` if you want to skip the line.